# How can I get text file path from console user input and and use it in an array?

Tags: c#, file, console

My code below gets a text file from a path stored in the code and then saves it to an array. I then proceed to separate the words from the previous array by using delimiters with the `Split()` method to divide any words that contain such delimiters (' ', ',', '.', ':', ';', '-') into two words.

It then save each separated word to a new array list which I save into a text file to a path also stored in code.

My code does what I want. How can I make it so that the file path is entered by the user through the console so that it can be passed into the array?

Also, how can I let the user enter a file path from the console for the new file to be in?

```
namespace TextParser
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Please enter location of the text file you would like to sort: ");
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (@"C:\Users\Desktop\dictionary.txt");
            System.Console.ReadKey ();
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ';', '-' };
            int wordCount = 0;
            ArrayList noDuplicates = new ArrayList();
            TextWriter writeToNewFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Desktop\dictionaryFIXED.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string wordsToSeparate = line;
                string[] newListWithDuplicates = wordsToSeparate.Split (delimiterChars);

                foreach (string word in newListWithDuplicates)
                {
                    if(!noDuplicates.Contains(word))
                    {
                        noDuplicates.Add (word);
                        Console.WriteLine (word);
                        wordCount++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach(string s in noDuplicates)
            {
                writeToNewFile.WriteLine (s);
            }

            writeToNewFile.Close ();
            Console.WriteLine (wordCount);
            Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for [System.Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will wait for the user to input a value and returns that value as a string. Typical usage might look like this: `string myFilePath = Console.ReadLine()`.  You could use that method for both problems in your question. Of course note that a user's input is not guaranteed to be a valid path for reading or writing, so you will need to verify their input and/or handle exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get user input, then attempt to read it with a try catch block

```
    Console.Writeline("Input file path");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    try{
      string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (input);
      //The rest of your code here
    }catch{
       Console.Writeline("You did not input a valid path");
    }
```